# Javascript not showing page heading and text in heroku at all

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a site here https://thatdevlevi.herokuapp.com/. When the page loads you might notice a huge grey blank area. That area is supposed to have a h1 and some text that fades via javascript removing the hidden class from the elements. Why is javascript not working? I have tried putting my javascript inside the asset pipeline (homepage.js) and on the view inside script tags and neither work, but if I run

```
Alert("test");
```

that works fine.

Application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PortfolioSite</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your heroku app has https and is requesting the jquery library using http causing an error, open the console! same goes for the images! transform the urls to https.

Comment: Share your layout (`application.html.erb`) file.

Comment: @Babar I added the file to the question.

Comment: @PaoloMangia I did open the console, I even kinda said that I did in the question above `n the view inside script tags and neither work, but if I run
Alert("test") that works fine. thanks in advanced for any help.` Sorry for not being as clear as I could have been about that. Also it is javascript that is giving me issues not jquery...and while yes I am getting those errors on my pictures they are still showing up and working, so I am leaving those issues until the bigger one which is actually affecting my site is handled. Thank you for pointing them out though.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the cdn I was using to get jquery to https instead of http and it fixed the issue

I would like to make a little apology to @PaoloMangia as he essentially suggested I do this to fix it and I fairly rudely blew him off on his suggestion.